# Nginx index.html gets overwritten with default index.html file

Tags: nginx

I'm running Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04. I have my website installed in the default `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory. My website works fine for several days and then the system automatically overwrites my websites index.html file with the default Nginx "Welcome to nginx!" index.html file. I have to go back and copy my website's index.html file again in order for my website to work.  I've had my website up for a couple of weeks now and this has happened three times. My website will work for a few days and then my index.html file will get overwritten. There is no method to the madness. Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?